# Converting an array containing structure to json

Tags: arrays, json, swift, serialization

I'm trying to convert an array into json but can't get it to work. It says the array is an invalid type to convert to json, but it's just an array of ints.

```
//These are for me to able to use time 

let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.current

//This is the structure that my array will be filled with    

struct Day
{
var week: Int?
var date: Int?
var month: Int?
var year: Int?
var weekday: Int?
}

//This is my array

var theArrayContainingAllTheUserData = [Day]()

var numberofloops = 0

//This is a loop that fills my array with data

while theArrayContainingAllTheUserData.count < 20
{

var theincreasingnumberofdays: NSDate {
    return NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: numberofloops, to: NSDate() as Date)! as NSDate
}

let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!

numberofloops=numberofloops+1

var ScoopDay =  Day()

ScoopDay.week=Int(myCalendar.component(.weekOfYear, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
ScoopDay.date=Int(myCalendar.component(.day, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
ScoopDay.month=Int(myCalendar.component(.month, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
ScoopDay.year=Int(myCalendar.component(.year, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))
ScoopDay.weekday=Int(myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: theincreasingnumberofdays as Date!))

theArrayContainingAllTheUserData.append(ScoopDay)

}

//And here is my failed attempt at converting it to json

do {
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: theArrayContainingAllTheUserData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
} catch {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Getting Error:**

> 2016-10-28 13:20:09.669 jsona arrayen[3284:332873] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'

```
First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010840834b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107e6921e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108471265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010795d284 _writeJSONValue + 668
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010795d6d9 ___writeJSONArray_block_invoke + 132
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001083ae36f __NSArrayEnumerate + 607
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010795d3df _writeJSONArray + 330
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010795d204 _writeJSONValue + 540
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010795cf94 -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] + 124
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010795ce74 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 333
    10  ???                                 0x0000000116ddd3cb 0x0 + 4678603723
    11  jsona arrayen                       0x0000000107892620 main + 0
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001083ad25c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108392304 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108391a75 __CFRunLoopRun + 901
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108391494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010d796a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000108f3bf34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    18  jsona arrayen                       0x00000001078926e9 main + 201
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b8e968d start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Share your raw JSON data

Comment: Could you log `theArrayContainingAllTheUserData`, just to be sure?

Comment: It's **not** *just an array of ints*, it's an array of struct `day`. Considering the naming convention that names of structs start with a capital letter avoids that kind of confusion.

Comment: I shortened the array to 5 indicies. Logging theArrayContainingAllTheUserData gives me [day(week: Optional(44), date: Optional(29), month: Optional(10), year: Optional(2016), weekday: Optional(7)), day(week: Optional(45), date: Optional(30), month: Optional(10), year: Optional(2016), weekday: Optional(1)), day(week: Optional(45), date: Optional(31), month: Optional(10), year: Optional(2016), weekday: Optional(2))]

Comment: Vadian - Point taken. Capitalized struct Day. Callam - I don't get far enough to actually get any JSON data

Comment: You cannot convert custom structs to JSON, only standard types number, string, <null> and collections array, dictionary containing those types are allowed. You need to map your struct to a dictionary or array. And consider to use non-optional properties, for example a real gregorian date has always a non-optional year.

Comment: What I really need is a way to convert the array to a String for storage and then turn it back into an array when retrieved again. Is there a simple way to do that that does not involve changing the structure of the array as it is here?

Comment: Add a computed property `arrayRepresentation` and return an array of the 5 properties, add also an initializer `init(array: [Int])` and assign the values to the 5 properties in the same order. Then you will have a mapper to convert an instance of the struct to `[Int]` and vice versa. And declare the date components properties non-optional, that makes things much easier.